# Как отправлять текстовые файлы от бота в telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Здравствуйте. Понятен принцип только с изображениями, но как брать рандомный файл из папки, отправлять его юзеру и после удалять этот же файл из папки?

Telegram бот, используется pyTelegramBotAPI (python)
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На [GitHub](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#telebot) есть замечательные примеры по передаче файлов. Для текстовых файлов используется метод `send_document` :

```
# sendDocument
doc = open('/tmp/file.txt', 'rb')
tb.send_document(chat_id, doc)
tb.send_document(chat_id, "FILEID")
```

Удалять файлы с помощью стандартного [os.remove()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove):

```
os.remove('/tmp/file.txt')
```

Comment: Спасибо, но неясно как брать рандомный файл, и удалять его же после отправки.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы отправлять рандомный файл и удалять его же – достаточно подключить библиотеку random, и использовать примерно подобный метод:

```
all_files_in_directory = os.listdir(directory)
file = random.choice(all_files_in_directory)
doc = open(directory + '/' + file, 'rb')
bot.send_document(message.from_user.id, doc)
os.remove(directory + '/' + file)
```

Answer (score 0):

я придумал такое, но не уверен что все правильно
я новенький в Python но у меня все работает. При нажатии на кнопку бот выбирает рандомный файл и отправляет его, а затем этот файл удаляет из папки.
код:

```
DIR = 'путь к папке с файлами/'
randFile = random.choice(os.listdir(DIR))
bot.send_document(message.chat.id, open(os.path.join(DIR, randFile)))
os.remove(f"путь к папке с файлами/{randFile}")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: По факту это совпадает с кодом из этого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/601145/1365